# Tag proposals - work

Tags: discussion, tags

Did anyone suggest *work* tag yet?

I think it would be interesting to have ability to say that the question comes from the work domain - either directly related to your work or indirectly.

Maybe it will give us ability to distinguish questions that are more 'real' or 'interesting' from questions that come from random curiosity (nothing wrong with that, but I think it is good to be *able* to distinguish).

The tag will have to be assigned by the poster and taken in good faith.

Thoughts?

Comment: Not that it is a big thing, but I assume downvoters are expressing their thoughts by downvoting. Shouldn't they rather vote up an answers that explain why it is is a bad idea? I mean what is wrong with the question (what can be improved) so that it deserved so many down-votes?

Comment: This is meta. Down or up votes are designed to represent agreement or disagreement.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is a bad tag. It feels to me like it would be a meta tag. It can't work as a tag for a question by itself.

[Meta tagging is discouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) because the tags do not describe the content of the question.

If a question is tagged [work](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work) what do you learn about the question? There is the [business-language](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business-language), so we don't need a new one for that.

I'm not sure what the [work](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work) would mean when added to a question. What aspect of English language or usage is it addressing?

Answer (score 1):

If the tag would be used to mean that the question is asked because of something related to work, then the tag is a meta tag, as it doesn't describe anything about the topic of the question; it describes the reason why you are asking.

As long as the questions are asked because of actual problems, the exact reason for which you are asking the question doesn't matter. If you are going to ask a question just out of curiosity, then you should not ask it. This is valid in any SE site, as the FAQ of any SE site contains the following paragraph:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.
>
> If your motivation for asking the question is "I would like to participate in a discussion about […]", then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is "I would like others to explain […] to me", then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat.)